# After Deploying to Heroku, Can't Login via Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my Dev environment, everything runs flawlessly.  But, after deployment to Heroku, I can't log in.  After filling out both the Sign in & Sign Up forms, I am redirected to the Root URL, but the UnAuthenticated page is shown and I do not have access to any of the Authenticated Routes.

**A few notes:**

- After Signing Up, a User record is created in the db
- After Signing IN, a Sign in Count is added in the db
- I am 100% confident the db is setup & migrated correctly (haven done this many times)
- Their are no errors in heroku logs.  It appears that I am simply
  redirected when trying to access Authenticated routes.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Getting desperate with this one :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem was in my session_store.rb file.  I had changed it to accomodate for subdomains, yet the :domain => was set to my local dev environment url (lvh.me).    I changed it to :all, and the app now works as it should.

Good luck!